# Using variable in bash command and collecting output in a variable is not working

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following command which, if fired with a hardcoded IP  works fine -

```
ad_request_output="$(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -w 0.18 -c 0.25 -H <Some private IP> -u 'http://<Some private IP>/fam/postGetAd.php?site_id=76986&partner_id=27de34b6f8b03d81&banner_id=183517&timeout=5000&version=1.5.1&language=jsp&format=wap&phone_headers=REMOTE_ADDR=>166.137.8.134||REMOTE_HOST=>http://localhost||HTTP_USER_AGENT=>Mozilla/5.0')"
```

`echo $ad_request_output` gives expected output -

```
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 217 bytes in 0.055 second response time |time=0.054961s;0.180000;0.250000;0.000000 size=217B;;;0
```

But, using a variable IP gives a different output -

```
private_ip=<Some private IP>
ad_request_output=$(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -w 0.18 -c 0.25 -H $private_ip -u 'http://$private_ip/fam/postGetAd.php?site_id=76986&partner_id=27de34b6f8b03d81&banner_id=183517&timeout=5000&version=1.5.1&language=jsp&format=wap&phone_headers=REMOTE_ADDR=>166.137.8.134||REMOTE_HOST=>http://localhost||HTTP_USER_AGENT=>Mozilla/5.0')
```

`echo $ad_request_output` gives -

```
HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request - 311 bytes in 0.001 second response time |time=0.000703s;0.180000;0.250000;0.000000 size=311B;;;0
```

Tried with this format of putting variable `${private_ip}` as well, but got same output -

```
 ad_request_output=`/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -w 0.18 -c 0.25 -H ${private_ip} -u 'http://${private_ip}/fam/postGetAd.php?site_id=76986&partner_id=27de34b6f8b03d81&banner_id=183517&timeout=5000&version=1.5.1&language=jsp&format=wap&phone_headers=REMOTE_ADDR=>166.137.8.134||REMOTE_HOST=>http://localhost||HTTP_USER_AGENT=>Mozilla/5.0'`
```

I checked some related questions [Bash - Using variable inside command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527197/bash-using-variable-inside-command-not-working) but got no clue what am I doing wrong.

I have working code to use variable in a command -

```
php /var/cake_1.2.0.6311-beta/beforeInstall.php ${OUTPUT}
```

But, not sure how to do it when the output needs to be collected in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` all characters inside `'` are preserved. That means that `$<variable>` is not expanded. See this:

```
$ something=value
$ echo $something
value
$ echo "$something"
value
$ echo '$something'
$something
```

In your specific case `$private_ip` would not be expanded to the value of `private_ip`. Relevant section from `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of
>   each character within the quotes.  A single quote may not occur
>   between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

The `private_ip` variable doesn't get expanded if you use single quote. You should use double quotes:

```
ad_request_output=$(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http -w 0.18 -c 0.25 -H ${private_ip} -u "http://${private_ip}/fam/postGetAd.php?site_id=76986&partner_id=27de34b6f8b03d81&banner_id=183517&timeout=5000&version=1.5.1&language=jsp&format=wap&phone_headers=REMOTE_ADDR=>166.137.8.134||REMOTE_HOST=>http://localhost||HTTP_USER_AGENT=>Mozilla/5.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Oliv already answered your question correctly. But I would like to add some help so that you can find the answer yourself in the future.

Given your script to begin with (I simplified the command):

```
#!/bin/bash
private_ip=127.0.0.1
ad_request_output=$(check_http -H $private_ip -u 'http://$private_ip/fam/postGetAd.php')
echo $ad_request_output;
```

You could simply call bash with the parameter -x, which prints every command before it is executed

```
bash -x test.sh
```

Output:

```
adiesner@local /tmp> bash -x test.sh 
+ private_ip=127.0.0.1
++ check_http -H 127.0.0.1 -u 'http://$private_ip/fam/postGetAd.php'
t.sh: Line 4: check_http: Command not found
[...]
```

You can clearly see that $private_ip was replaced once, but not the second time.

Another way is to simply output the command by placing "echo" in front of it.

```
#!/bin/bash
private_ip=127.0.0.1
ad_request_output=$(echo check_http -H $private_ip -u 'http://$private_ip/fam/postGetAd.php')
echo $ad_request_output;
```

Output:

```
adiesner@local /tmp> ./test.sh
check_http -H 127.0.0.1 -u http://$private_ip/fam/postGetAd.php
```

As soon as you know what is going on it should be easy to enter the correct search words.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging tip.